# KeyError in Python | How to make two divs side by side in Python for dynamic data

Tags: python, html, css

1. media.py: http://pastebin.com/r1nxPzTQ

   This is class file. Containt `__init__` and another method `show_trailer(self)`.
2. fresh_tomatoes.py: http://pastebin.com/bcdUYiiu

   A Python file which writes an HTML file and fills data from the Python file below. **Problem Here**
3. entertainment_centre.py: http://pastebin.com/rv36mH6s

   Creates objects from `media.py`'s `Movie()` class.

---

My problem is that when I try to place two div's side by side in the following manner:

```
movie_tile_content = '''
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 movie-tile text-center" data-trailer-youtube-id="{trailer_youtube_id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#trailer">
        <img src="{poster_image_url}" width="220" height="342">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 movie-tile text-center">
        <h3>{movie_title}</h3>
        <h5>{movie_storyline}</h5>
    </div>
</div>
'''
```

This gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Udacity\Project-1 Movies Trailer\entertainment_centre.py", line 37, in <module>
    fresh_tomatoes.open_movies_page(movies)
  File "C:\Python27\Udacity\Project-1 Movies Trailer\fresh_tomatoes.py", line 164, in open_movies_page
    movie_tiles=create_movie_tiles_content(movies))
  File "C:\Python27\Udacity\Project-1 Movies Trailer\fresh_tomatoes.py", line 153, in create_movie_tiles_content
    trailer_youtube_id=trailer_youtube_id
KeyError: 'movie_storyline'
```

Why is a **`KeyError`** occurring when I am using the same variable name as I used in `media.py` file.

**EDIT : 1**
Updated `media.py` code : http://pastebin.com/gSgBfTuG

Updated `fresh_tomatoes.py` code : http://pastebin.com/EjuXT9M9

Updated `entertainment_centre.py` code : http://pastebin.com/Z0Ct512L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lines 150-154 you need to add something to the `movie_storyline` placeholder.

```
content += movie_tile_content.format(
            movie_title=movie.title,
            poster_image_url=movie.poster_image_url,
            trailer_youtube_id=trailer_youtube_id,
            movie_storyline="this movie is about things..."
        )
```

Comment: Hey thank you! that worked.. But another problem which is occurring is that only one `tile` is loaded! Why other content from `entertainment_centre.py` file not loaded ?

Comment: Josep :  Please look at the updated links I have put in the question description. I made necessary changes but, the poster_image of only first movie gets initialized . Why don't other poster images get rendered ?

Comment: That looks like a different problem unrelated to this question. I'd ask you to accept my answer and open a new question but before, I'd recommend you try to debug the code step-by-step to see what may be happening now.

Comment: Can you look at my recent question on Python DB API please ?